# How to add a field from a file in logstash filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a logstash pipeline with many filters, it ingests netflow data using the netflow module.

I would like to add one field to the output result. The name of the field being: "site"

Site is going to be a numeric value present in a file. How do I create the field from the file?

Eg:

```
 mutate {
        id => "site"
        add_field => {
            "[flow][policy_violation]" => "false"
            "[flow][threat]" => "false"
            "[flow][site_id]" => //=======> read file /tmp/site.id and assign value 

        }
    }
```

File:

/tmp/site.id

site.id contains:

12345678

Comment: So `flow.site_id` is constant for all events on the same host? Also how do you start Logstash?

Comment: Yes. The flow.site_id once set, will remain a constant throughout. The reason I want it to be read from a file is because of prod installation. I start logstash using docker. I don't mind having an env variable that can be read to populate this field as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage an [environment variable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html) in the Logstash configuration. First, export the variable before running Docker/Logstash:

```
export SITE_ID=$(</tmp/site.id)
```

Then run docker with the environment variable:

```
docker run ... --env SITE_ID
```

And then in your Logstash configuration, you can reference the variable like this:

```
mutate {
    id => "site"
    add_field => {
        "[flow][policy_violation]" => "false"
        "[flow][threat]" => "false"
        "[flow][site_id]" => "${SITE_ID}"

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I can work with this. However, I would also like to know how to make use of ruby script. I tried similar to this,  https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-ruby-plugin-to-get-the-value-from-file-and-append/29895

But I run into rubyexception

Comment: With the ruby filter you're going to re-open and re-read the file for each event again and again... are you sure you want all this IO to occur?

Comment: Hm. It actually doesn't make any sense to do that. Specially since the file content never changes. :)